# Runtime Error in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net

I am modifying a website using asp.net pages which was created using asp. In the web.config file I am using

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" tarrgetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

and also tried

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error.htm"/>
```

But still an error occuring as

**Runtime Error**

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

What is its solution??

Comment: Check that you are editing the right file, and putting it in the right place. If the setting actually is as the error message describes, that error message will not show up. Until you get the error message with more information, it's very hard to tell what's causing it.

Comment: When I am running it offline then there are no errors,but running online causing the error & All the pages are stored in the wwwroot directory.

Comment: If you are still seeing that error message, then the web.config file that you edited isn't used. You can add a deliberate mistake in the file to see it it's used, as that would give a different error message.